# How to get a human-readable dump of .git/index?

Tags: git

**short version**

How can I get a reasonably detailed, human-readable dump of `.git/index`?

---

**tl;dr version**

I have two index files, `myrepo/.git/index` and `myrepo-copy/.git/index` that are different according to `diff` ("Binary files ... differ").

I'd like to know more details on how the two index files differ.

Of course, I could look at the differences in the binary content, but I'm interested in something more immediately meaningful.

Therefore I'm looking for a way to get human-readable dumps of these two index files that I can compare with `diff`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
diff <(GIT_INDEX_FILE=/path/to/index1 git ls-files --stage) <(GIT_INDEX_FILE=/path/to/index2 git ls-files --stage)
```

As you've already noted, you can add the `--debug` option to get info on timestamps and other stuff as well...

Answer (score 5):

OK, after I posted my question I learned that the following produces a fairly comprehensive dump of the index:

```
% git ls-files --stage --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to solve your problem is to commit the changes that are in one of the index files to a temporary branch, e.g.

```
git checkout -b temp
git commit
```

and then copy the other index file you have over `.git/index`.  You can now use `git status`, `git diff --staged` etc to see the differences.