# What does `git checkout-index -u` or `--index` do?

Tags: git

The [`git checkout-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index) command copies files from the index to the working tree.

The documentation includes a cryptic remark about its `-u` or `--index` command-line parameter:

> **-u**
>   **--index**
>   update stat information for the checked out entries in the index file.

What is "stat information?" What's the difference between updating it and not updating it?

I find that in simple experiments, `git checkout-index` just writes files to the working tree, as you'd expect; I can't see any difference between using `-u`/`--index` and not using it.

Comment: Do you see the mtime of `.git/index` change?

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me who finds it cryptic. To me, checkout in the context of git means switch branches, and index is something to do with files modified. So understanding how I'd use it is tough (even though I bet it would be useful!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-checkout-index` copies data *from* the index *to* the working tree. `git-update-index` copies metadata *from* the working tree *to* the index.

These are low-level commands which need to be specifically told what to do.
That this option exists at all is <s>a wonder of user interface design</s> a useful option to ensure that git's index reflects a consistent view of the working tree after the operation has been performed.

Specifically, this updates (at least) the metadata that *doesn't* contribute to a git repository but rather is used to determine if files are unchanged. See [How to get a human-readable dump of .git/index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305543/how-to-get-a-human-readable-dump-of-git-index) and [What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-contain-exactly).

Added in [415e96c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/415e96c8b7e7d47f98a45ae1b6d524418245a3b4).

By way of an example, I'll follow along with `t/t2002-checkout-cache-u.sh`, which runs the command first without and then with `-u` (again, that's "the equivalent of git update-index --refresh on the checked out entry").

1) preparation:

```
echo frotz >path0 &&
git update-index --add path0 &&
t=$(git write-tree)
```

2) without -u, git checkout-index smudges stat information.

```
rm -f path0 &&
git read-tree $t &&
git checkout-index -f -a &&
git diff-files --exit-code
```

output of diff-files:

```
:100644 100644 8e4020bb5a8d8c873b25de15933e75cc0fc275df 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M  path0
--> 1
```

see what's in the index:

```
$ git ls-files --debug
path0
  ctime: 0:0
  mtime: 0:0
  dev: 0    ino: 0
  uid: 0    gid: 0
  size: 0   flags: 0
```

3) with -u, git checkout-index picks up stat information from new files.

```
rm -f path0 &&
git read-tree $t &&
git checkout-index -u -f -a &&
git diff-files --exit-code
```

(returns 0)

now the stat(2) is there:

```
$ git ls-files --debug
path0
  ctime: 1491479474:0
  mtime: 1491479474:0
  dev: 16777220 ino: 50556411
  uid: 501  gid: 20
  size: 6   flags: 0
```

Apart from the stat information being recorded, there's one other interesting bit in the output. Why does `git-diff-files` say there are differences between the working tree and the index?

The manual says that field in the output is

> sha1 for "dst"; 0{40} if creation, unmerged or "look at work tree".
>
> <sha1> is shown as all 0’s if a file is new on the filesystem and it is out of sync with the index.

So this test case is illustrating one way git uses the metadata information: When comparing files in the working tree and the index. If the stat information looks stale (or all zeroes), then the file might have changed. Since `git-read-tree` only writes to the index, and not the working tree, it necessarily invalidates the stat information. And if the stat information is valid, `git-diff-files` can confidently give the blob ID for that entry.

Answer (score 0):

While `git-checkout-index` does copy data from the index to the working tree, it has an annoying bug before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021): "[`git checkout-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92d6bd2e9064200b14f3730b674eb8eb7b7cd50e/Documentation/git-checkout-index.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index))</sup> did not consistently signal an error with its exit status.

See [commit 7e41061](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e41061588eab25d0c015e79aa8d04956bee482a), [commit 0b809c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b809c82480a870f4a46fa66f0eddc1c1b04cf6b) (27 Oct 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 92d6bd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92d6bd2e9064200b14f3730b674eb8eb7b7cd50e), 09 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`checkout-index`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e41061588eab25d0c015e79aa8d04956bee482a): propagate errors to exit code
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> If we encounter an error while checking out an explicit path, we print a message to stderr but do not actually exit with a non-zero code.
>
> While this is a plumbing command and the behavior goes all the way back to [33db5f4d90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33db5f4d9027a10e477ccf054b2c1ab94f74c85a) (Add a "checkout-cache" command which does what the name suggests., 2005-04-09, Git v0.99), this is almost certainly an oversight:
>
> - we *do* return an exit code from `checkout_file()`; the caller just never reads it
> - errors while checking out all paths (with "`-a`") do result in a non-zero exit code.
> - it would be quite unusual not to use the exit code for an error, as otherwise the caller has no idea the command failed except by scraping stderr
>
> To keep our tests simple and portable, we can use the most obvious error: asking to checkout a path which is not in the index at all.